# dconf-service using 11.5GB RAM on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, ram, dconf

Running Kubuntu 20.04.on Samsung Ultrabook, 12Gb RAM, 32GB Ssd, 500GB HDD.
The OS is installed on the SSD and all my files are on the HDD.

After latest update, the fan run high and  the Computer became unresponsive.
System Monitor showed that CPU was 100% and 'dconf-service' and 'woopsie' used more and more memory, up to using all my 12GB.

On a forum someone said that woopsie can be removed, so I purged it, but that just freed some RAM for dconf to gobble up. 
If I stop 'dconf-service'I can access the Terminal, but cannot start Chrome or Firefox

If I boot via the USB installation drive, can read through all the drives (SSD, HDD, external 1T HDD etc).

I have not been able to do a proper full backup.  Tried with
`sudo rsink -aXS DirName/. DestDir/.`  but that only copied all my directories, no files and lots of errors

I need some help to either fix the problem OR get a full backup before I re-install Kubuntu.

Comment: This is very late, but I think you're supposed to delete stuff inside /var/crash. I think it's trying to send a report? Anyways you already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying all files in my internal HDD to an external HDD using the live disk and FreeFileSync.

Then reformatted SSD and HDD and done a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.10.
Re-copied all files to internal HDD and now all works fine.